# Error opening the wallet kdewallet

Tags: permissions, kde, kde-neon

I did a fresh install of KDE neon a while ago and I cannot figure out how to solve this problem:
When I start my laptop and try to connect to a wifi network, even the networks I connected to before, I get asked to create a new kde wallet. I choose "Classic, blowfish encrypted file". I get prompted to choose a password. When I press enter then, I get the alert

> "Error opening the wallet 'kdewallet'. Please try again. Error code -2: Error opening file."

I guess the problem is that KDE doesn't have the permissions to write to a certain file, I just couldn't figure out which file that is.

Systems Specs:

- Operating System: KDE neon 5.18
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.3
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
- Qt Version: 5.14.1
- Kernel Version: 5.3.0-42-generic
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
- Memory: 7,7 GiB of RAM